# Github Desktop always shows 'No content changes found'

Tags: windows, github-desktop

#### Environment

- Operating system: Windows
- git version: 2.29.2
- Github Desktop version: 2.6.3

#### Description

I am working on my repository using vscode, and I can see the diff of my changes on vscode. After committing my changes, when I go to Github Desktop, I can see all my previous commits but whenever I click on one of them, I see `No content changes found`. This problem appeared only a few days ago, so I guess this is a bug in Github Desktop.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

I got this when I changed folder permission using **chmod** command

after disable checking filemode on git solved the issue

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly questions out the way - you are on the right branch? There actually were files changed? You have re-added the repositories to GitHub desktop again - maybe a git history / cache issue?

With no content changes found it sounds like you are comparing a branch that has no changes to itself? I.e. there is no difference. Could be worth raising it on [github support](https://support.github.com/request) if there were expected changes and you are seeing none - but sounds like a git history issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem occurred when moving the repo folder from local to OneDrive. Moving it back resolved it. Unsure if there were some permissions needed to make it behave properly or if this is standard behavior.